# Intermittent nslookup DNS request timed out

Tags: dns, internet, nslookup

My home internet has felt a bit clunky for the last week. If I run nslookup on a site it seems to timeout about 1 out of every 5 times, while working fine the other attempts.

```
>nslookup www.google.com
DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
Server:  UnKnown
Address:  8.8.8.8

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    www.google.com
Addresses:  2607:f8b0:400a:80b::2004
          142.250.217.100
```

- I'm having this problem on two different computers (both windows 10)
- I tried without my router and connected directly to my modem and the problem persists. (I did a modem reset and that jazz.)
- I've tried different DNS servers (my ISP, google and openDNS) and there's no change.
- I've also tried rebooting, dns flushing, and some basic network reset commands.

What does work:

- No problems when I Ping something.
- If I enable my VPN nslookup works fine.

I want to say it's an issue with my ISP but that might be jumping to conclusions.
Does anyone have an ideas of what might be going on, or what else I should do to troubleshoot?

Comment: Can you do some packet loss measurement, both to the DNS servers and to various other sites in general? `ping -t 8.8.8.8` and waiting a few minutes to collect some stats would be a good start.

Comment: Also, can you get a response out of `nslookup google.com 203.0.113.2` or `198.51.100.3`? (This is to detect DNS interception by the ISP. Normally those addresses should *not* respond.)

Comment: Pinging 8.8.8.8 was fine; < 1% packet loss. 
I got no response from the fake DNS addresses you suggested (as expected)

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a problem with my ISP - I saw a forum post suggesting other people are having a similar issue.

I did a bit more testing myself. I used wireshark and found out that some of the DNS lookup requests are just not getting responses (regardless of the DNS server).

I've started a support ticket with my ISP and will probably just wait it out at this point.